# Assigning one array to another javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, copy

So array in javascript are assigned by references so for example

```
let a = [1,2,3];

let b = a;

a = [];

console.log(b);
```

Shouldn't it print empty array as a is assigned to empty array and b and a are point to same.

Comment: no. `a` has now a new object reference.

Comment: a and b both point to one memory and you are making a refer to another. that doesnot change b

Answer (score 0):

I know that such behavior might seem weird. However, as other writers already mentioned, what happens is that by writing ‘a = []’ you actually assigned ‘a’ a new reference (i.e. you are not manipulating the ‘old’ array any more), and ‘b’ will hold an old reference to a memory location where ‘old’ array was initially assigned and *break* a relationship with ‘a’. Hence, there will now exist 2 references instead of an initial 1.